# How to speed up mouse beyond fastest setting in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

The fastest mouse speed available in the mouse properties dialog in Win 7 is not fast enough for me. Is there a way to make the mouse go faster than that?

EDIT:

On my mac I'm using [this](http://www.tylernichols.com/apple/speed-up-mouse-tracking-on-mac-os-x), there must be some sort of equivalent for windows?

Comment: Try calling Tim Allen. ;)

Comment: If the mouse doesn't scan the ground underneath it fast enough it can't get faster without starting to get choppy (going 3 pixels per step, etc). Bottom line: Get a mouse with high DPI.

Comment: Call up the control panel app for the mouse, get a felt marker, extend the speed slider line and mark the end line with 11. Use your mouse to drag the little button to 11. Or check out who the manufacturer of the mouse is, go to their website and see if they have an updated driver with better mouse ballistics. If the mouse doesn't have the resolution, you need a new mouse.

Comment: gotta go fast... Ps.: Get some uber-gamer mouse with 10k+ DPI.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/469044/how-to-increase-mouse-sensitivity-beyond-limits-in-windows-regedit

Answer (score 1):

Some mice have their own drivers which will allow you to change their DPI setting which can effect how "fast" they move across the screen.  You can also enable cursor acceleration in your mouse settings, that may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Daisetsu; there's no driver for this mouse, and acceleration is on... There must be some sort of way to set the value directly wherever windows is storing it, along the lines of http://www.tylernichols.com/apple/speed-up-mouse-tracking-on-mac-os-x?

Comment: @korneel even if you could, you would eventually get to the point where the mouse pointer does no longer moving smoothly across the screen and jumps between points because there is no data for the intermediary points (this is why Daisetsu mentioned DPI).