# More Precise Windows Sensitivity Multiplier

Tags: windows, mouse

I'm trying to set my mouse sensitivity more precisely. I want to set it to exactly 0.7x, but Windows does not have that option

Currently, these are the sensitivity options in Windows:

> 1/11 - 0.0625x
>
> 2/11 - 0.0125x
>
> 3/11 - 0.25x
>
> 4/11 - 0.50x
>
> 5/11 - 0.75x
>
> 6/11 (default) - 1.00x
>
> 7/11 - 1.50x
>
> 8/11 - 2.00x
>
> 9/11 - 2.50x
>
> 10/11 - 3.00x
>
> 11/11 - 3.50x

Is there any application/script that will give me more control over Windows mouse sensitivity?

Source:
http://wiki.teamliquid.net/counterstrike/Mouse_settings#Windows_Sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can do this with a registry change. Found a suggestion on another question https://superuser.com/a/1310313/389381

> 1. Run regedit.exe from the Windows search bar
> 2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
> 3. Change MouseSensivity to 20 (10 = normal, 20 = twice as fast)
> 4. Restart your PC